# failed when I was trying to use defuse-inject pattern in dplyr group_map function

Tags: r, dplyr, mapreduce, tidyr, xts

Following is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
library(dplyr)

tbl.data <- tidyquant::tq_get(c("GS", "C", "BAC"))

to.xts <- function(group, group_key, date_col, price_col){
  a <- group %>% dplyr::pull({{ price_col }}) 
  b <- group %>% dplyr::pull({{ date_col }})
  x <- xts::xts(a, order.by=b)
  colnames(x) <- key$symbol
  x
}

make.xts <- function(data, date_col, price_col){
  data %>% 
   group_by(symbol) %>%
   group_map(~to.xts(.x, .y, date_col, price_col))
}

# Failed example one:
tbl.data %>% group_by(symbol) %>% group_map(to.xts, date, close)

# Failed example two:
make.xts(tbl.data, date, close)

# Error in `dplyr::pull()`:
# ! Can't extract column with `!!enquo(var)`.
# ✖ `!!enquo(var)` must be numeric or character, not a function.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

# However, If I single out a group myself and apply `to.xts` to that group it'll work. The only thing changed, which I doubt that it would have effect on the function itself, is that the `group_key` is now a string (it was a data-variable in the context of `group_map`'s `.f`)

gs.grp <- tbl.data %>% dplyr::filter(symbol=="GS")
gs.grp %>% to.xts("GS", date, col)
 
# A simply pull operation would also work.

gs.grp %>% dplyr::pull(close)
```

I don't quite understand what has changed internally; why this is the case and what's not correct here?

Given the error message that it seems `dplyr::pull` is doing
defuse (`enquo`) and inject (`!!`) itself internally, therefore I shall not use embracing operator; however, without it it didn't work either and caused the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `group_map` function much , here is an alternative version that you can try -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tbl.data <- tidyquant::tq_get(c("GS", "C", "BAC"))

to.xts <- function(group, symbol, date, price){
  a <- group %>% dplyr::pull({{ price }}) 
  b <- group %>% dplyr::pull({{ date }})
  x <- xts::xts(a, order.by=b)
  colnames(x) <- symbol
  x
}

tbl.data %>% split(.$symbol) %>% imap(~to.xts(.x, .y, date, close))
```

If you want them in one `xts` object as separate column.

```
tbl.data %>% 
  split(.$symbol) %>% 
  imap(~to.xts(.x, .y, date, close)) %>%
  {do.call(merge, .)} 

#             BAC     C     GS
#2013-01-02 12.03 41.25 131.66
#2013-01-03 11.96 41.39 130.94
#2013-01-04 12.11 42.43 134.51
#2013-01-07 12.09 42.47 134.26
#2013-01-08 11.98 42.46 133.05
#2013-01-09 11.43 42.04 134.32
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `group_map` using a formula to apply to each group:**

```
library(dplyr)
#library(xts)

tbl.data %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  group_map(~ to.xts(.x, .y, date, close))

to.xts <- function(group, group_key, date, price) {
  a <- group %>% dplyr::pull({{ price }}) 
  b <- group %>% dplyr::pull({{ date }})
  x <- xts::xts(a, order.by = b)
  colnames(x) <- group_key
  x
}
```

Very similar notation to `purr` that it is based on.

> In the formula, you can use
>
> . or .x to refer to the subset of rows of .tbl for the given group
>
> .y to refer to the key, a one row tibble with one column per grouping variable that identifies the group

(See the documentation)

**Alternatively, we could also use pivoting to avoid your function, and put it inside one `xts`-object.**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#library(xts)

tbl.data %>% 
  pivot_wider(date, names_from = symbol, values_from = low) %>%
  xts::xts(order.by = .$date) %>%
  .[,-1]
```

Output:

```r
           GS    C      BAC   
2013-01-02 "130" "40.7" "11.9"
2013-01-03 "130" "41.0" "11.9"
2013-01-04 "130" "41.6" "11.9"
2013-01-07 "133" "42.0" "12.0"
2013-01-08 "133" "42.0" "11.9"
2013-01-09 "133" "41.8" "11.3"
2013-01-10 "134" "42.0" "11.5"
```

Comment: very interesting; it should actually lead me to the same result according to documentation, i.e., a formula with `.x` and `.y` and a function with at least two formal args (`group`, `group_key`); but it seems your formula has worked, whereas passing in a function directly did not.

Comment: I have never seen it used that way (neither in the examples in the documentation or elsewhere), but at the time speaking, I understand why it could be the intended behaviour.

Comment: I guess you are referring to the demos in example section of `?dplyr::group_map`; indeed there's no demonstration for using an anonymous function; however a formula and an anonymous function shall both work, only that a formula is more backward compatible (detailed in `Arguments` section).

Comment: I've edited my question as well, my apologies that I missed a key piece of info; when I re-read my code I found that I tried formula already which was wrapped around by a function.

Comment: I am afraid I do not have a clear answer to why it doesn't work. I guess the key is to use something else than `{{ }}`-notation if it's wrapped twice.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but I wanted to point out that this is much less complicated if you avoid the tidyverse patterns completely.

```
symbols <- c("GS", "C", "BAC")

# Environment to hold data
my_data <- new.env()

# Tell getSymbols() to load the data into 'my_data'
getSymbols(symbols, env = my_data)

# Combine all the close prices into one xts object
price_data <- Reduce(merge, lapply(my_data, Cl))

# Remove ".Close" from column names
colnames(price_data) <- sub(".Close", "", colnames(price_data), fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks Joshua; indeed, I shall spend more time exploring existing `base-r` and `xts` facilities; having been using `tidyverse` stuff for sometime now, I found the codebase becoming a bit cumbersome now unfortunately.

Comment: Using tidyverse is fine if you want to stay in that paradigm. But you wanted xts objects, so it's easier to avoid tidyverse and stick with the underlying xts implementations.

Comment: I wanted a bit of both at the outset given most of the analytical functions were built around `zoo` and `xts` and tidyverse provides some readability from a different point of view (not that base r, `quantmod` or `xts` is not). But yeah, if things started with pure `xts` it would be equally readable as well.

Comment: On a side note, I've noticed your warning on `dplyr::lag`, does that mean as long as `dplyr` is installed, `stats:lag` is not going to work correctly until `dplyr` fixes it?

Comment: @stucash It's only an issue if dplyr's namespace is loaded or it's attached (i.e. you've attached dplyr or another package that uses it). If you're not concerned about the warning, you can set the option to suppress it (`options(xts.warn_dplyr_breaks_lag = FALSE)`)

Comment: I just read your comment on `dplyr` github as well thanks a lot.